# Jquery checking the upload filename in file type input

Tags: jquery, file, file-upload

I was trying to check the filename by the filename format given using JQuery..

this is my code:

`<input class="" name="myfile" id="myfile" type="file" multiple="false" data-value="">`

my JQuery Script:

```
function checkFileName(filename, file_id){
    var must_filename;

    must_filename = jQuery(file_id).attr('data-value').split('.').slice(0, 2).join('.');
    jQuery('.file_err_det').remove();
    alert(must_filename + ' != ' + filename);
    // filename value is always null?
    if(must_filename != filename){          
        alert('Filename is not valid! Please follow the format and upload it again');
        jQuery(file_id).val('');
    }
}

jQuery('#myfile').blur(function() {
    var this_filename = jQuery(this).val().split('.').slice(0, 2).join('.');
    checkFileName(this_filename, '#myfile');
    alert(this_filename); // this returns null? I dont know why..
});
```

but it seems the value `this_filename` is null. I am using `blur`, is there anything that I can use to check the `jQuery('#myfile').val()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Using files from web applications](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications)

> The File API makes it possible to access a FileList containing File
>   objects representing the files selected by the user.
>
> If the user selects just one file, it is then only necessary to
>   consider the first file of the list.
>
> Accessing one selected file using a classical DOM selector:
>
> `var selectedFile = document.getElementById('input').files[0];`
>
> Accessing one selected file using a jQuery selector:
>
> `var selectedFile = $('#input').get(0).files[0];`
>
> `var selectedFile = $('#input')[0].files[0];`

---

Try utilizing [change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event

```js
$("#myfile").on("change", function(e) {
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  console.log(file, file.name);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input class="" name="myfile" id="myfile" type="file" multiple="false" data-value="">
```