# To Upload files by dynicamically created file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In the below code i am trying to implement dynamic file upload without using any server side controls . I want to create document and attachment file upload.When i click upload for document the file should get upload .When i click attachment corresponding multiple attachment under that document should be uploaded.I tried the below code it doesn't work.Pls help me to do this.

JS:

```
 var counter = 0;
    function AddFileUpload() {
        var div = document.createElement('DIV');
        div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" name = "file' + counter +
                     '" type="file" />' +
                     '<input id="Button' + counter + '" type="button" ' +
                     'value="Remove" onclick = "Upload(this)" />';

        div.innerHTML = '<input id="files' + counter + '" name = "files' + counter +
                     '" type="file" />' +
                     '<input id="Butn' + counter + '" type="button" ' +
                     'value="Upload" onclick = "UploadFiles(this)" />';
        document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
        counter++;
    }
    function Upload(div) {

    }
    function UploadFiles(div) {

    }
```

Asp.net:

```
<span style ="font-family:Arial">Click to add files</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="add" onclick = "AddFileUpload()" />
    <br /><br />
    <div id = "FileUploadContainer">
        <!--FileUpload Controls will be added here -->
        Documents:<input type="file" name="file0"  id="file0" />
       Attachments: <input type="file" name="files0" multiple id="files0" />
    </div>
    <br />
```

Comment: What is not working ??? `counter` should be set to **1** initially..First element already exists in `DOM`

Comment: @Rayon Dabre When i click Add only one file upload get dynamically added and not the other one.And i want to upload files of documents and attachment s

Comment: Not certain what expected result is ? `counter` is not incremented ? Second `div.innerHTML = ..` overwites first `div.innerHTML = ..` ? Second `.innerHTML` could be `div.innerHTML += ..` ? What is purpose of creating two `input type="file"` elements ?

Comment: @guest271314 One is for single document upload and another one is multiple attachments for that document to be uploaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second `div.innerHTML = ..` overwrites first `div.innerHTML = ..` ? Try substituting [Addition assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment) `+=` operator for `=` at second `div.innerHTML`

```js
var counter = 0;

function AddFileUpload() {
  var div = document.createElement('DIV');
  div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" name = "file' + counter +
    '" type="file" />' +
    '<input id="Button' + counter + '" type="button" ' +
    'value="Remove" onclick = "Upload(this)" />';

  div.innerHTML += '<input id="files' + counter + '" name = "files' + counter +
    '" type="file" />' +
    '<input id="Butn' + counter + '" type="button" ' +
    'value="Upload" onclick = "UploadFiles(this)" />';
  document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
  $("[id^=file]").on("change", function(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    console.log(file, file.name);
  })
  counter++;
}

function Upload(div) {
  console.log(div)
}

function UploadFiles(div) {
  console.log(div)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<span style="font-family:Arial">Click to add files</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="add" onclick="AddFileUpload()" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="FileUploadContainer">
  <!--FileUpload Controls will be added here -->
  Documents:
  <input type="file" name="file0" id="file0" />Attachments:
  <input type="file" name="files0" multiple id="files0" />
</div>
<br />
```

Comment: How to get the file name and path ?

Comment: @Dotnet _"How to get the file name and path "_ Can retrieve `File` object `name` property within `change` event for `input type="file"` element ; cannot retrieve path to file on user filesystem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359599/jquery-checking-the-upload-filename-in-file-type-input

Comment: I tried the code like this  $('#file' + counter + '').on("change", function (e) {
            alert();
            var file = e.target.files[0];
            alert();
            alert(file);
            console.log(file, file.name);
        })   not working .No alert is working

Comment: Thanks For Attachment multiple file upload it displays only one file

Comment: @Dotnet Try removing `[0]` from `file` variable , using loop to retrieve each `File` object from `FileList` , see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications